# How to add custom payment method with form only for admin

Tags: admin, custom, payment-methods, ce-1.8.1.0

I am using Magento CE 1.8.1.0.

I have successfully added a custom payment method with a simple form with one field: custom fee in the admin area. I am storing the value in the info instance additional_data field. I can see this value being saved in the database. However, I want this value to be added to the Totals block at the same time because I will add a new row called "Custom Fee" in this block.

Unfortunately I don't know how to pass the captured value "custom fee" to my `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` subclass. The `fetch()` method is not able to get the custom fee value from the `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address` object:

```
public function fetch(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address) {

  $info = $address->getQuote()->getPayment()->getInfoInstance();
  // $info is null because custom fee has not been persisted
  ...
}
```

What is the best approach to pass the custom fee value from the form to `fetch()` in my `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Abstract` subclass?